# UI-GRID Height Of Grid Percentage Of The Screen Area

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

What is the best way to handle the height of the ui-grid. We want to have it take up 85 percent of the screen and the footer take up 15%.

Whey I set the height of the grid to 85%, it doesn't do anything.

When I change the px height, that pushes the screen down.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A grid's height, when defined as a percentage, is relative to the height of its parent container. This is the same as any other HTML element.  If the parent element *only* has the grid in it, then there's nothing to be 85% of.

This is because the grid virtualizes its content. Despite having, say, 500k rows in its data set, it has no idea how many of them it should be showing at a time.

Luckily in your case, setting the grid height with [viewport percentage](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) would probably work:

```css
.grid {
  height: 98vh;
}
```

That tells the grid to be almost the full height of the browser viewport (note that 100vh is a bit too much).

See this plunker for a demo: http://embed.plnkr.co/65ScOLedYpm1rSKztQkE/preview

There's some more information in this post: http://brianhann.com/make-ui-grid-take-up-the-whole-page/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, that's a crazy way to do height. I didn't know about **viewport percentage**! Good stuff!